The security token included in the request is invalid in @WebMvcTest
When i'm trying to test simple controller call
mockMvc.perform(post("/api/v2/test-flow/{key}", key)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
                .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(body)))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())

i'm getting following exception
Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.simplesystemsmanagement.model.AWSSimpleSystemsManagementException: The security token included in the request is invalid.

How to exclude aws (i'm not sure from where it is appeared) from the call and just test my controller method?

You need to share a lot more information about your test and setup if you want to get any help.
